# Disable duplicate select on dataTable

Tags: ajax, jsf, select, primefaces, datatable

When selecting the same row twice (on a Primefaces DataTable), the `rowSelect` ajax behavior gets fired both times. Is there any way to optimize this and don't update the second time when the same row is selected?

Note: 
Primefaces 5.0

Comment: what do you mean by selecting the row twice? you mean, you want to toggle the row state?

Comment: You mean do not update the component on action success?

Comment: I have a table and a panel: when selecting a row, the panel displays details of the selected row. I want to avoid selecting the same row again and updating the panel with the same data the panel is already displaying.

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 5.0

Comment: Give an example of code jsf and bean